# Как заставить PhpStorm добавлять фигурные скобки для условий if?

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm при написании `if` создает блок `if()`.
Хотелось бы всегда получать сразу

```
if(){

}
```

Comment: Не нашел этого фрагмента в Live Templates. Как вариант, можно создать собственный шаблон для этого сокращения.

Comment: @Neolot было бы удивительно если бы нашли, ибо я его там тоже искал, перед тем как задавать вопрос.

Comment: Думаю, что этот шаблон зашит внутри IDE, и тогда решением будет сделать свой шаблон. Так даже удобнее, можно сделать на свой вкус.